# tf.signal.rFFT in TFLITE is not working in JAV

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, audio, tensorflow-lite

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution (Android 10,11):
- TensorFlow installed from : source
- TensorFlow version: 2.4.1

I am simply trying to make a model which takes time series data as input and compute rFFT/irFFT and return time series data.
I used tf.signal.rfft and tf.signal.irfft for computations. I have converted it to TFLITE and its working perfectly fine in python. But when I load it into android studio it gave me Null in interpreter. Following is code for python:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Lambda, Input
import tensorflow as tf

inp = keras.Input(shape=((197429)))
O = Lambda(stftLayer)(inp)
Z = Lambda(istftLayer)(O)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=Z, name="fft_model")

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS ]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('FFT.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

When I give voice signal to this TFLITE model on python it returns same signal perfectly. But When I Load it into Android studio and run following code, it do not load TFLITE model properly and show NULL in Interpreter :

```
private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile() throws IOException {
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = this.getAssets().openFd("FFT.tflite");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
FileChannel fileChannel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
long startOffSets = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffSets, declaredLength);

}
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
Interpreter tflite;

try {
tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run model it gives
**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference**

Following is gradle setting:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dtln_test"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    aaptOptions{
        noCompress = "tflite"

    }
    buildFeatures {
        mlModelBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    //implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:+'
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   // implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.1.0-rc1'
  //  implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-metadata:0.1.0-rc1'
//    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated !!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Resolved.
While Making TFLITE with custom functions/Lambda Layers, do these steps while making tflite.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS ]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

and in android studio add these in dependicies:

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'

implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-select-tf-ops:0.0.0-nightly-SNAPSHOT'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the null exception is raised because the TFLite interpreter creation is failed with some reason. It would be better to verify whether the interpreter object is initialized well or not, first.

I would suggest adding a statement for logging the error while creating the interpreter instance like the below code snippet:

```
try {
    tflite = new Interpreter(loadModelFile());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TFLite", "failed to create TFLite interpreter instance", e);
}
```

If there is an error occurring in the Interpreter creation, you can find the corresponding error in the logcat section in the Android studio.

Then, we can debug the reason why it is failed to be initialized.

Comment: This is the Log result..Although I have added the file in assets folder..

.
TFLite: failed to create TFLite interpreter instance  java.io.FileNotFoundException:FFT.tflite

Comment: RFFT2D operator is supported through the Select TF op option. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select Please refer to the following link to add one more dependency to enable the Select TF option: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#android_aar

If you have a concern on the binary size of the Select TF option, you can do the selectively built aar by your own. See also https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/reduce_binary_size

Comment: For the file not found exception, if you do not have the following option in the build.gradle, please add them not to compress the TFLite file and make it readable through the fd descriptor:
android { 
  ...
  aaptOptions {
    noCompress "tflite"
  }
}

Comment: Thankyou very much. Issue resolved by adding dependencies.